# powershell how to add items to dictionary and then add the items in that list to another dictionary?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to parse values from an XML file that will add items to a collection using a foreach loop, then add the items from that collection to another collection using another foreach loop with an addition value.  This is what I am doing so far:

```
[xml]$testResults = Get-Content -Path $testResultsPath
$resultsByName = @{}
$resultsByPhone = @{}
$loop = 0
foreach($testCase in $testResults.'test-results'.'test-suite')
{
    foreach($testCase in $testResults.'test-results'.'test-suite'[$loop].'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.
    'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-suite'.'results'.'test-case')
    {
    $NameWithPone = $testCase.name.ToUpper().Substring($testCase.name.LastIndexOf('.')+1);  
    $Name =$NameWithPone.Substring(0, $NameWithPone.IndexOf('_'));
    $PhoneVersion = $testCase.name.Substring($testCase.name.IndexOf('_')+1);
    $resultsByName.Add($PhoneVersion, $Name)
        Foreach($resultCase in $resultsByName)
        {
            $resultsByPhone.Add($resultsByName, $testCase.result)
        }
    }
$loop++
}
```

But this will only add it first result, then give the error `"Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 
'System.Collections.Hashtable'  Key being added: 'System.Collections.Hashtable'"`  I think this is because I am adding the same item each time, how can I correct this?

The first collection will look like this:

```
google_pixel_xl-7_1_1          TESTTHATAREGISTEREDUSERCANLOGINTOTHECUSTOMERAPPSUCCESSFULLY                 
htc_10-6_0_1                   TESTTHATAREGISTEREDUSERCANLOGINTOTHECUSTOMERAPPSUCCESSFULLY                 
oneplus_one-4_4_4              TESTTHATAREGISTEREDUSERCANLOGINTOTHECUSTOMERAPPSUCCESSFULLY
```

But I want to add both values together to another collection which would look like:

`google_pixel_xl-7_1_1 TESTTHATAREGISTEREDUSERCANLOGINTOTHECUSTOMERAPPSUCCESSFULLY   Error`

Comment: Looks like you are forgetting to increment `$loop` at the end of the outer loop

Comment: I forgot to add that sorry fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this done by doing this:

```
[xml]$testResults = Get-Content -Path $testResultsPath
foreach($testCase in $testResults.'test-results'.'test-suite')
{
    function Get-TestCases($myResults)
    {
        $testCases = @()
        foreach($child in $myResults.ChildNodes)
        {
            if($child.'test-case' -eq $null)
            {
                foreach($testCase in Get-TestCases $child)
                {
                    $testCases += $testCase     
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $testCases += $child.'test-case'
            }
        }
        return $testCases
    }
    $tests = Get-TestCases $testResults.'test-results'.'test-suite'[$loop]
    foreach($test in $tests)
    {
         $PhoneVersion = $test.name.Substring($test.name.IndexOf('_')+1);

         $resultsByPhone.Add($PhoneVersion, @{})
         $NameWithPhone = $test.name.ToUpper().Substring($test.name.LastIndexOf('.')+1);    
         $Name =$NameWithPhone.Substring(0, $NameWithPhone.IndexOf('_'));

         $resultsByPhone[$phoneVersion].Add($Name, $test.result)           


    }
    $resultsByPhone[$phoneVersion] 
    $resultsByPhone
    $loop++
}
```